# Adding ACL records for FreeBusyReader

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to add a new ACL record to add a domain as freeBusyReader as described [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl).

Whenever I POST to 
`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/r...@resource.calendar.google.com/acl` with a **new** domain I receive an error:

```
# Request
{
    "scope": {
        "type": "domain",
        "value": "domain.com"
    },
    "role": "freeBusyReader"
}

# Reply 
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "notFound",
                "message": "Not Found"
            }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

Weirdly though, it works for domains for which there is already *some* ACL rule. Those I can even change, so I assume that neither existence of the resource nor authorization is not the problem as suggested in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this documentation about [How to update the ACL of a Google Calendar with the Google APIs Explorer](http://googleappstroubleshootinghelp.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-update-acl-of-google-calendar.html). If the user you want to grant access to is included in the response, you can proceed to update the ACL of the calendar.

For more info:

- [Working with ACl in Google Calendar](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+ACL+in+Google+Calendar)